# Problemas em uma crud class

Tags: php, classes, crud

Estou tentando construir uma classe para ser utilizada com mysql a principio tenho so dois arquivos então vou colar o codigo que ja fiz aqui e explicar minha duvida.

```
classes/connect.php

<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: evtns
 * Date: 08/06/2016
 * Time: 17:55
 */
class Database
{
    private $db_ip = '127.0.0.1';
    private $db_user = 'root';
    private $db_pass = 'aaxd31mubr';
    private $db_select = 'sistema';

    public function connet(){
        $dbc = mysqli_connect($this->db_ip,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass) or die("falha ao conectar");

        if(mysqli_select_db($dbc, $this->db_select ))
        {
            echo 'DB selecionado com sucesso <br />';
            return $dbc;
        }
        else{
            echo 'falhou';
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function select($cols='*',$tables ,$where=null, $value=null, $order=null)
    {
        $query = "SELECT $cols ";
        $query .="FROM $tables ";

        if(isset($where) and isset($value))
        {
            $query .="WHERE $where='$value'";
            echo 'teste 1 ok';
        }

        if(isset($order))
        {
            $query .="ORDER BY $order";
        }

        if($result_query = mysqli_query($this->connet(), $query)){
            return $result_query;

        }
        echo 'Falha ao executar querry da função select.';
    return false;
    }
}



index.php

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: evtns
 * Date: 08/06/2016
 * Time: 18:33
 */

include_once 'classes/connect.php';

$db = new Database();
//$cols='*',$tables,$where, $state//


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->select('*', 'estado'));

print_r(array_count_values($row));

?>
```

Meu problema está aqui fiz uma instância da classe, mas ao tentar acessar os elementos do result_query da public function select, com mysqli_fetch_array(), ele so me retorna o primeiro elemento do banco, agora se tentar direto na função ele me retorna todos os valores cadastrados no banco.

alguém sabe como resolver este problema?

Comment: o banco lhe retornará um array de resultados, você precisará de uma estrutura de repetição para navegar por eles

Comment: Já que esta iniciando, recomendo utilizar conexão PDO, pois émais prático e seguro.

Comment: Segue no meu gitHub uma classe que facilita a comunicação com PDO. Possui até metódos que facilita a inserção/edição => https://github.com/LucaoA/connectionPDO/blob/master/Connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, apenas criei uma variavel para receber o valor da função e utilizei da variavel para manipular os dados!

segue exemplo do codigo!

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: evtns
 * Date: 08/06/2016
 * Time: 18:33
 */

include_once 'classes/connect.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db = new Database();
//$cols='*',$tables,$where, $state//
$result = $db->select('*', 'tbl_clientes');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'] .' ID '. $row['nome'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em usar a função **array_count_values**
O sistema acaba parando devido existir campos que não sejam STRING ou INTEGER.

Substitua o final do index.php pelo seguinte código:

```
$db = new Database();
//$cols='*',$tables,$where, $state//


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->select('*', 'estado'));

echo "<pre>" . var_dump(($row));
```

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->select('*', 'tbl_clientes'));
    for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i){
       echo 'ID' . $i . $row['id'] . '<br />';
    }

fiz desta maneira agora e ainda sim recebo so o primeiro valor do banco de dados. agora se eu deixar o codigo acima na função abaixo que fica dentro da class database ele imprime todos os valores do existentes no banco de dados!

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->select('*', 'estado'));